# How did E "congee" come from L "commeatus", with an intrusive "g"?

Tags: etymology

***[congee](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/congee#Etymology)***

> From Old French **congié** (modern congé), from **commeatus** ("passage, permission to leave"), from **commeo** ("I go and come"), from con- + meo ("I go, I pass")

Occasionally I find this word, but I can't help being curious about the change from "-mm-" to "-ng-".

Comment: Some useful links http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/cong%C3%A9 , http://www.etymologiebank.nl/trefwoord/conge and http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cong%C3%A9

Answer (score 2):

The sound change isn't really mm > ng, but rather [mj] > [nʒ].

The combination /j/+front vowel underwent fortition in other Romance languages, including Italian (L. iactare > Italian gettare).

In the case of *congee*, I would propose *commeatus* -> [komjet] -> [komʒet] (fortition) -> [konʒet] (assimilation). The OED etymology has Provençal *comjat*, *conjat*, which confirms the last sound change.

Comment: L. commeatus > LL. comiatus etc.

Comment: Some **attested** forms, from the Dictionnaire historique de la langue francaise (Rey 1998, t.1): cumgiet (v.980), congiet (v.1050), conged (v.1130). They also propose the following intermediate stages: *comyadu, *condjiado.